# Looking for example xml to generate a Findbugs report using ANT to analyse multiple jars?

Tags: ant, static-analysis, findbugs

How do I setup an Ant task to generate a Findbugs report when the source folder has many jars in it?

I'm looking for a worked example of the ant task required to output the fancy HTML from a folder containing multiple jars

Answer (score 1):

[FindBugs Ant target](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/anttask.html) to generate the report in XML format, then apply one of the XSLT transformations that come with your FindBugs installation via the standard [Ant XSLT target](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/style.html).

Answer (score 1):

This thread is 2 years old but maybe someone will find it useful:

You can do it easily:

```
<class location="${src.dir}/test.jar" /> 
<class location="${src.dir2}/test2.jar" />
```

Assuming you have 2 source path you should define them before:

```
<sourcePath path="first source path" />
<sourcePath path="second source path" />
```